# RewriteCond confusion

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I have the following rewrite setup:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/?.*$ api.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ web.php [L]
```

What I want is for non-files and directories to be caught by api.php or web.php (which do their own routing), and the rest to return the file or directory. However, the main route `'/'`, seen by mod_rewrite as `''` doesn't get caught - I guess this is because / is a directory - the root.

How can I fix this so that it goes through to web.php while keeping directories accessible?

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll want to change REQUEST_URI in your rules to REQUEST_FILENAME. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

> REQUEST_URI:  The resource requested in
>   the HTTP request line.
>
> REQUEST_FILENAME:  The full local
>   filesystem path to the file or script
>   matching the request.

Then, add another rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule .* web.php [L]
```

So the final result would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/?.*$ api.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)? web.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule .* web.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax: RewriteBase URL-path

URL-path can be root relative path or empty. Empty URL-path value means that rule base will equal to web site root.